# Python double for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm having trouble with my loops. I get an error for 400 being out of range. Am I applying something that is not allowed, or what is my issue? It looks like legal syntax to me?

```
survTime=np.array([400, 800, 1100, 900])
age=np.array([40, 40, 40, 40])
counter_1yr=0
counter_2yr=0
counter_3yr=0
n=1
for i in survTime:
     for j in age:
        if survTime[i] > 365 and age[j] < 50:
            counter_1yr+=1
            n+=1
            continue
        elif survTime[i] > 730 and age[j] < 50:
            counter_2yr+=1
            n+=1
            continue
        elif survTime[i] > 1095 and age[j] < 50:
            counter_3yr+=1
            n+=1
            continue
print("1 year probability: ", counter_1yr/n)
print("2 year probability: ", counter_2yr/n)
print("3 year probability: ", counter_3yr/n)
```

Comment: `for i in survTime` does not give you a counter from `0 -> len(survTime)` it gives you the actual values of survTime one by one. You do not need to access the arrays by index after that. The way you are doing it, one the first loop will yield the call `if survTime[400] > 365 and age[40] < 50:` - which is clearly out of range. You can just do if `i > 365 and j < 50:`

Comment: Possibly a manifestation of the XY problem. Try to ask about the original problem X you are trying to solve instead of asking about how to implement the solution Y you conceived (it is OK to show what you have tried so far).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing values with indexes. In Python, the `for x in ...` syntax returns each of the elements in an iterable object, *not* the indexes. Try this instead:

```
for t in survTime:
     for a in age:
        if t > 365 and a < 50:
        # and so on
```

Notice that you intended to iterate over the *values* of each array, but in reality you're using each item as an *index*, which is way out of bounds - for instance: `survTime` doesn't have `400` elements! For completeness' sake: if you really needed the indexes, the way to traverse a list called `lst` would be:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    ele = lst[i] # do something with the element
```

Answer (score 2):

`for in` enables you the iterate over items, not index. I would guess you want to have

```
for i in survTime:
    for j in age:
        # now i == survTime[0] and j == age[0]
        if i > 365 and j < 50:
            # more code
```

Or if you want to work with index, use `for i in range(len(survTime))`
Or if you want to work with both, use `for index, value in enumerate(survTime)`